# PowerAutomate Flow: Fails with TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, power-automate

I have a PowerAutomate flow where I am trying to add a user in ADO using REST API. PFB snapshot of the step where it fails. This is the error:

> code: 401 - "TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required."

REST API CALL to ADD User in Azure DevOps Org:;

[image]

The credentials used to establish a connection between ADO and PowerAutomate have Project Collection Administrator privileges as well in Azure ADO. The same REST API when called from PowerShell with the same credentials, just works fine. But when called from flow it fails.

Any pointers on how to resolve this issue would be very helpful.

Comment: I did try using HTTP task as well to achieve this. But it did not succeed then. Let me try and get back to you on this. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes. Please try it. Feel free to let me know the result. If you have any questions, you could share it with me

Comment: Tried using HTTP, GET works fine! But POST/PATCH/PUT fails with the same error! Is it like this versions of the API is not yet completely supported by FLOW? Because the earlier versions when used some time back - worked perfectly fine. So was wondering what could be the issue.

Comment: You could try to convert the format (`name:PAT`) to based64 in this site and set it in Auth header. https://www.base64decode.org/ . On the other hand, you can try to create a PAT with full access and check if it could work

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the same issue when I use the Action:"Send Http Request to Azure DevOps".

To Solve this issue, you could use the Action "Http" with the same settings .

[image]

Then it will work.

[image]